# Disable map panning using the arrow keys in the keyboard

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a Leaflet map and I want to completely disable panning whether using the mouse, touchscreen, or keyboard, so that the map appears like a static image. I have added `map.dragging.disable();` which works for mouse dragging.

But when the map container is focused using the Tab key, pressing the arrow keys on the keyboard will still pan the map. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281202/disable-map-panning-using-the-arrow-keys-in-the-keyboard

Answer (score 4):

I think that there are a couple options on Leaflet maps that should resolve your issue.

First, the dragging option, if false, should prevent the mouse from dragging the map.
[image: the dragging option]

Next, the keyboard option, if false, should prevent the user from navigating the map with the keyboard.
[image: the keyboard option]

Also, you should consider setting doubleClickZoom to false if you want your map to be static.
[image: the doubleClickZoom option]

Finally, examine the [map option documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-option) to ensure that I haven't missed any relevant options.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great info. I did not know about the `doubleClickZoom` until you mentioned it. Thank you very much.